# Does IBM api connect support POST multipart/form-data request?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am trying to publish a api which uses multipart/form-data request but it seems ibm api connect doesn't support it but I wanted to have a confirmation. Also I couldn't find a way to upload file option in the api connect ,only relevant parameter type they are providing is string binary.Could someone share their info regarding this.

Comment: OpenAPI 2 supports multi-part and API Connect imports OpenAPI 2. Have you tried defining such an API? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/

Comment: TYFA. Yes you are right about that but I did try one multipart test API and when trying to test it using explore API option in APIC it was not able to recognize the request. I found one IBM support link:https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/support-web-form-api-connect-post-http-requests-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and-multipartform-data-content-types       regarding the same and was trying gateway script and proxy options but didn't have any luck till now.